# PHP - refer to stdclass object within array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to refer to **value** below:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [label] => John Smith
        [attributes] => Array (
            [class] => sf-level-0 sf-item-14
        )
        [value] => smith-john
        [depth] => 0
        [count] => 3
    )
    [1] =>... etc.
```

**QUESTION**

Assuming the array is called **$array**, what would be the right format for this? I've tried `array[0]->['value']`, but it does not work.

Comment: $array[0]->value should be what you needed. Did you forget the `$`?

Comment: I had the `$` - just added it here as well. This worked, thank you for answering and reformating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tough to say with your formatting. but:

```
$array[0]->value
```

The first element in the array is of type `stdClass Object`, so to access its members, you use the object accessor `->` rather than the array syntax.

PS: Kudos to Marc for making things legible with his edit.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!